# Перебор в массиве

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Есть массив с координатами, через любые 2 точки проходит вектор, нужно найти максимальное кол-во коллинеарных векторов. К примеру из 4 точек можно составить 6 векторов. Я написал перебор, но использую 4 цикла и делаю лишние проверки. Как можно улучшить данный перебор?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 2 ; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            createVec(&t1, arr[i], arr[j]);
            for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
                for (int l = k + 1; l < n; l++)
```

это часть кода

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понятно *максимальное* в "максимальное кол-во коллинеарных векторов".

Если вас устраивает перебор - то

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
    for(int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
{
    Найти угол - скажем, через atan2, он корректнее
    Сложить в массив (размер массива известен заранее)
}

Отсортировать массив по этому углу
```

Дальше - просто идете по массиву и смотрите, если два значения рядом совпадают (помня об особенностях сравнения `double`) - вот коллинеарность и найдена. Тут же можно посмотреть, сколько таких совпадающих - 2, 3 или, скажем, 15 :)

Comment: А зачем искать угол, когда тупо достаточно тангенса? то бишь deltaY/deltaX?

Comment: @Akina Потому что тангенс может быть и бесконечным, а угол - нет :)

Comment: Ну если в С две бесконечности равны - то нет проблем. А если не равны - ну придётся на этот случай отдельную проверку сделать.

Comment: @Akina А если они достаточно близки? :) Трудно будет писать сравнение для двух близких, но очень больших значений. Ну, это уже пусть думает автор вопроса, как для него лучше считать..

Comment: Надо вести вычисление в дельтах. Тогда вместо `dXa/dYa = dXb/dYb` проверяем `dXa*dYb = dYa*dXb`. И чхать на нули.

Comment: Массив это хорошо, но при больших значениях, например 1000, придется создать массив на 499 500 элементов

Comment: @VladF Обратите внимание - я написал *"Если вас устраивает перебор"*.